# Drag and drop for Angular 1 material grid layout

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I want to drag different (angular material) grid layout from one container to another. While dropping the layout it will automatically fit into that container.

Comment: I have build something like this before, see if it works for you

https://github.com/odeskvaibhav/Kanban-Board-Application-based-on-AngularJS-Material-Design

Answer (score 2):

I use [dragula](http://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/).

It's as simple as:

```
dragula([document.getElementById(left), document.getElementById(right)])
  .on('drag', function (el) {
    el.className = el.className.replace('ex-moved', '');
  }).on('drop', function (el) {
    el.className += ' ex-moved';
  }).on('over', function (el, container) {
    container.className += ' ex-over';
  }).on('out', function (el, container) {
    container.className = container.className.replace('ex-over', '');
  });
```

*Disclaimer: I do not work nor did ever work for bevacqua... :-)*